.NET MAUI Editor does not scroll to new line when text is added programattically
I'm using a read only editor to show progress of a long operation.  On Windows and iOS, the editor is not scrolling to the bottom once the number of lines exceeds the viewable area.  It works as it should on Android.
Here's a sample that demonstrates what I see.  If you manually enter text into the first editor (editorOne), it will automatically scroll as you hit enter.  This does not happen if you add text via the top button.
Can anyone suggest a workaround to this bug?
EDIT:
I've already attempted using CursorPostion = editorOne.Text.Length-1.  This moves the cursor but will not scroll the editor.
EDIT 2:
The following works on Windows when added to the TextChanged event, but on iOS it causes the keyboard to display:
editorOne.CursorPosition = editorOne.Text.Length - 1;
editorOne.Focus();

Still looking for a solution for iOS...
XAML:
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiEditorScrollTest.MainPage">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Text="Click button to add text.  Once editor is full, does editor scroll so new text is visible?"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Text="Add Line of Text" Clicked="Button_AddText_Clicked"/>
        <Editor Grid.Row="2" x:Name="editorOne"/>
        <Editor Grid.Row="3" x:Name="editorTwo" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="4" Text="Erase All" Clicked="Button_Erase_Clicked"/>
        
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>

And Code Behind:
namespace MauiEditorScrollTest
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        int LineNumber = 1;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_AddText_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            editorOne.Text += "Added Line " + LineNumber + Environment.NewLine;
            editorTwo.Text += "Added Line " + LineNumber + Environment.NewLine;

            LineNumber++;
        }

        private void Button_Erase_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            editorOne.Text = "";
            editorTwo.Text = "";
            LineNumber = 1;
        }
    }

}


AFAIK, that's not a bug, it's the default behavior for each platform. You can try setting the cursor to the end of the text: editorOne.CursorPosition = editorOne.Text.Length-1;

I've already tried the cursor position route.  It changes the cursor but does not scroll to it.

OK. Did you already check the MAUI repo for existing issues (bug reports/feature requests)?

I've not found anything there or anywhere else to help get by this problem.  Still digging.

Not ideal, but to hide the keyboard on iOS in case it opens, you could await editorTwo.HideSoftInputAsync(CancellationToken.None);. I'm just wondering why that happens if your Editor is read-only. Maybe another reason to file potential bug.

Earlier today I tried editor.HideKeyboardAsync() which results in a ridiculous user experience...screen bouncing due to rapid display/removal of keyboard.  I just tried HideSoftInputAsync and it yields the same result.

I've found a work around.
For Windows, setting the cursor position to the end and focusing the editor causes it to scroll to the bottom:
#if WINDOWS
editorOne.CursorPosition = editorOne.Text.Length - 1;
editorOne.Focus();
#endif

For iOS, you can grab the underlying UITextView and do the following:
#if IOS
NSRange range = new NSRange(0, editorOne.Text.Length);
// Grab the underlying UITextView object
var uiTextView = editorOne.Handler.PlatformView as UIKit.UITextView;
uiTextView.ScrollEnabled = true;
uiTextView.ScrollRangeToVisible(range);
#endif

